# Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined Ember CLI project

Tags: ember.js

I've opened up this project for this first time and tried to run it with `ember serve` I have seen a couple of answers on here regarding the same error and their solutions don't solve this problem.

None of the files in the stack trace point to any of the application source files. Can anyone shed any light?

```
Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
    at CoreObject.module.exports.massageVersionNumber (C:\Users\Adam Copley\Desktop\pop-two\node_modules\ember-welcome-page\index.js:110:19)
    at CoreObject.module.exports.included (C:\Users\Adam Copley\Desktop\pop-two\node_modules\ember-welcome-page\index.js:28:31)
    at CoreObject.superWrapper [as included] (C:\Users\Adam Copley\Desktop\pop-two\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\core-object\lib\assign-properties.js:32:18)
    at EmberApp.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Adam Copley\Desktop\pop-two\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\broccoli\ember-app.js:468:15)
    at Array.filter (native)
    at EmberApp._notifyAddonIncluded (C:\Users\Adam Copley\Desktop\pop-two\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\broccoli\ember-app.js:463:45)
    at new EmberApp (C:\Users\Adam Copley\Desktop\pop-two\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\broccoli\ember-app.js:138:8)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Adam Copley\Desktop\pop-two\ember-cli-build.js:7:13)
    at CoreObject.module.exports.Task.extend.setupBroccoliBuilder (C:\Users\Adam Copley\Desktop\pop-two\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\models\builder.js:74:19)
    at CoreObject.module.exports.Task.extend.init (C:\Users\Adam Copley\Desktop\pop-two\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\models\builder.js:54:10)
```

Comment: may be you can try  uprading node version

Comment: Is the project newly generated? What is the version of Ember CLI? What is the version of Ember.js used in the project? What is the version of Node.js? What is the version of npm?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue and solved it by removing the `ember-welcome-page` module (`yarn remove ember-welcome-page`). After that, everything ran fine! None of my other dependencies had any issues.